# How to write a part of the constructors of childs only once?

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, parent-child

I'm currently working with an abstract class Room which has seven different child classes. I am getting sick of copy-pasting a part of the constructor of one of the children to the other six if I add something to the abstract class (like a name property).

In what way don't I break the DRY principle when adding a property that has to be set the same/instantiated for each child?

Example:

```
public abstract Room
{
    // Need to be assigned in constructor.
    protected int RoomNumber { get; set; } 
    protected int PositionX { get; set; }
    protected int PositionY { get; set; }

    // Always the same at the start
    protected List<Guest> GuestsInRoom { get; set; }
    protected string ImageFilePath { get; set; }
}

public class Bedroom : Room
{
    private string Classification { get; set; }
    public Bedroom()
    {
        // Assign/instantiate all properties.
    }
}

public class Bathroom : Room
{
     private string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
     public Bedroom()
     {
         // Assign/instantiate all properties again
     }
 }
```

Comment: You set the property in the base class instead, and make each subclass constructor chain to the base class constructor. If you could provide a concrete example rather than a description, it'll be a lot easier to show you what the concrete solution looks like.

Comment: I was writing a quick example as you commented it. Anyways, What you are suggesting is `protected List<Guest> GuestsInRoom { get; set; } = new List<Guest>` instead of having the property in Room and the instantiating in the constructor of each child?

Comment: Not really. Unfortunately even with the example in place, you haven't shown any repetition. You should show at least two subclasses that contain the repeated code, so we can work out what should be extracted to the base class.

Comment: I thought with the context given above the example it was clear what I meant.

Comment: No, it really isn't. The idea of a complete example is to show what you're trying to improve/fix. If you're trying to remove repetition, that means you need to show where the repetition currently occurs.

Comment: I mean, we may be able to *guess* where the repetition would be, but with a good question we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Ah, like that. Then sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor to the base class. If there are fields that have to be assigned, make them required parameters. You can call the non-empty parent class constructor with  " : base()", shown in the modified Bedroom class.

```
public abstract Room
{
    // Need to be assigned in constructor.
    protected int RoomNumber { get; set; } 
    protected int PositionX { get; set; }
    protected int PositionY { get; set; }

    // Always the same at the start
    protected List<Guest> GuestsInRoom { get; set; }
    protected string ImageFilePath { get; set; }

    protected Room(int roomNumber, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        RoomNumber = roomNumber;
        PositionX = positionX;
        PositionY = positionY;
        GuestsInRoom = new List<Guest>();
    }
}

public class Bedroom : Room
{
    private string Classification { get; set; }
    public Bedroom(string classification, int roomNumber, int positionX, int positionY) 
        : base(roomNumber, positionX, positionY)
    {
        // Assign/instantiate all properties.
        Classification = classification;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, and with the `: base()` on the constructor you tell the constructor to also call the constructor of the base clase. Thanks!